# Terminal application that appends CR to incoming LF's on COM

Tags: windows, terminal, terminal-emulator, crlf, com-port

Is there any windows based terminal application that has a setting to allow carriage returns to be added to line feeds that come in from a COM port? 
I am currently using HyperTerminal and as far as I can work out this does not provide this.

Or to say that another way, the data I have coming in on a COM port is terminated by a line feed but without a carriage return. I would like the terminal display of the incoming data to act as if there WERE carriage returns, as well as line feeds, so that everything lines up nicely in the terminal window instead of stepping, or staggering, across the window until it wraps.

I have used other terminal programs, such as TeraTerm, before but cannot remember if any of them had this feature available.

EXTRA: Just noted that one of the transmitted non-printable characters (EOT or 0x04) is not showing in the terminal, although the sender is sending it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little while searching through old forums myself I found bray's terminal (https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/) which has a handy little check box marked "CR=LF" and does exactly what I require, re the CRs and LFs.

Now only to find how to switch to raw serial to see the EOT chars...

Comment: Apparently the EOT char thing would require a program that gets the raw serial bytes directly from the serial port driver - of which there are a few, though they all seem to only work on pre-vista windows as far as I can see :(